# Obtener la URL de respuesta del servidor con c#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, llevo un buen rato intentando lo siguiente y no veo que me acerque a la solución.

Necesito enviar una url del tipo www.dominio.com para que el servidor me devuelva www.dominio.com/index.html, por ejemplo. Vamos, el default page del dominio.

Tal y como tengo la lógica, utilizar un objeto webbrowser me complicaría mucho la vida, en su lugar, me sirve cualquier otra clase como HttpWebResponse, WebClient o lo que queráis.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde sé, solo podrás obtener esa información si el servidor te redirecciona con un 301/302 y te envía la nueva url en la cabecera "Location". Para esto debes desactivar la redirección automática y revisar las cabeceras:

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.q-protex.com");
http.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var response = http.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response.Headers["Location"]);
```

Pero si el servidor no usa redirección y tiene configurado un index.html, index.php o algún otro archivo como el predeterminado, este dato no aparece en las cabeceras.

Comment: Claro. He visto muchos códigos sobre el redireccionamiento, pero lo que me ocurre es precisamente lo último, el servidor no usa redirección y sus respuestas son del tipo 200. Es curioso que no haya o no encuentre una solución, no chapuza, para esto.